# Difficulty getting a copy paste formula to work and compress the paste area

Tags: excel, vba

I've been working on some code for an excel macro to copy and paste a large bit of data into a smaller portion but I keep getting runtime error 1004 saying that paste special method of range class failed.

I have tried changing the paste area and code used to selecting the range, or naming the range, pasting into a single cell and several different types and ranges of paste including using the exact same area.

```
Sub CAPAN()
'
' CAPAN Macro
'

'
    Range("Compressed_Associates").Clear
    Range("Associate_List").Clear
    Range("Uncompressed_Associates").CurrentRegion.Copy
    Range("Compressed_Associates").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("Compressed_Associates").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>"
    Range("Compressed_Associates").Copy
    ActiveSheet.Range("Compressed_Associates").AutoFilter Field:=1
    Sheets("Weekly Associate Data").Range("F8").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Columns("L:L").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    End Sub
```

The code fails at the `Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll` section and it causes the runtime error 1004, I have also gotten error 438 when I change the type of copy or paste I use but can't seem to get past this part.

Comment: This should be because of Using `Selection` , Can you not put a range instead of selection ? Because you are not selecting anything in your code, your selection would be the manual cell that you must have selected last while working in the workbook and code would be trying to paste data there.

Comment: I tried changing `Sheets("Weekly Associate Data").Range("F8").Select` to include a named range, and `Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll` to include a named range as well and several variations of one using a named range and the other not, both including and both excluding a named range but still no luck.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You do several `PasteSpecial`. Which one of them fails? Have you trying debugging your code? Execute it step by step with F8 and check every line.